# Java - LWJGL - OS X Retina Support

Tags: java, lwjgl, retina-display

I searched so long for a solution to run a simple LWJGL application on my MacBook Pro with Retina display. The problem is that the Retina display is flickering. But I just found uninformative hints.

Do you know any code solution to handle this? For example changing the viewport or something?

What have I to add to the following code?

```
import org.lwjgl.LWJGLException;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.Display;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.DisplayMode;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11;

public class MainDisplay {
    final int DISPLAY_WIDTH = 640;
    final int DISPLAY_HEIGHT = 480;

    public void start() {
        try {
            Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(DISPLAY_WIDTH, DISPLAY_HEIGHT));
            Display.create();
        }
        catch(LWJGLException exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }

        while(!Display.isCloseRequested()) {
            Display.update();
        }

        Display.destroy();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you actually try to render anything?

It sounds like the back buffer contains garbage data, and you're not painting anything in that loop. Every time you invoke the `Display.update()` it flips the back-buffer, and if you've not painted on it then you get the flickering of garbage data.

Try something like:

```
while(!Display.isCloseRequested()) {
    GL11.glClear(GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL11.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    GL11.glEnd();
    Display.update();
}
```

Which clears the display before flipping the back-buffer.

In general, if you don't actually display anything then you're at the whims of the graphics driver and memory as to what ends up on the screen. If I used your code, I see the following in the window:

[image: Garbage Display Output]

Comment: Oh god, your so right. I tried to solve a problem which is not a problem :)